# Display count in ADF pie chart

Tags: oracle-adf

When we create a pie chart in ADF (12.2.1.0.0), we get the pies that represent percentages.

e.g if we have a chart by job Id and salary, it shows the percentage of salaries for that job, but
1) How can we display the count of values(number of salaries) in that pie?
2) how can we display the value (total of salaries) in that pie.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a view object that uses queries to get the data you want and then base your chart on that VO.

Something like 
Select count(Salary), DepartmentId
From Employees
Group by DepartmentId

Comment: Thanks Shay, but when we hover, at that time it shows the count value, but in graph by default, it shows percentages.

Comment: There are a bunch of formatting tags you can use on charts - some examples in this video - http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/12cdemos/DVTChartsFormatting/DVTChartsFormatting.html